# How to authorise App Engine app to connect to Firebase realtime database?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

At the moment, I am building a logic backend on App Engine. I am following the tutorial on [GCP's blog](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine) but with a change that the App Engine service is not going to be a user. I have a service account for IAM and made the service account as project owner but I am still getting 401: Unauthorized every time the app wants to talk to Firebase.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMeyer

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMeyer,  the admin SDK just recently updated with Python SDK. Before this only Node.js and Java. Unfortunately,  I can only use to verify ID token.

Most of the functionalities that I wrote mostly targeted to write data back to database as admin rather than user for business logic that is more server-side. I am looking forward to when the Firebase team update the Python SDK to enable access to Realtime Database for Admin.

Comment: We need a python SDK for Firebase Realtime DB access too, as we are also using GAE.

Comment: @Jonny , you can try pyrebase. That is what I am using right now.